# Put string in new line after 64 character

Tags: python, string

I want to put \n after every 20 character....

```
My_string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffff"
```

I tried with this: `a = "\n".join(re.findall("(?s).{,20}", My_string))[0:-1]`

When ever i am print like:

```
print '''
              ---------------------------------------------------------------
               Value of a is 
            %s
              ---------------------------------------------------------------
        ''' % a
```

OUTPUT:

```
     ---------------------------------------------------------------
                          Value of a is
                          aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc
cccccccccccccccccccd
ddddddddddddddddddde
eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef
fffffffffffffffffff
                          ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want output like:

```
           ---------------------------------------------------------------
           Value of a is 
           aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
           bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc
           cccccccccccccccccccd
           ddddddddddddddddddde
           eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef
           fffffffffffffffffff
           ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did you mean to have only 19 a's?

Comment: The space from left to characters (aaaa.. or bbbb.. or cccc ...etc) is 30 spaces(changeable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a list of all lines, both predefined and wrapped, then add space identation in front of each one (preferably in a single step to avoid duplicate code) and then join everything into a single string.

While regular expressions do the trick, have a look at a nice standard module `textwrap`, which allows you to wrap lines:

```
import textwrap

My_string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffff"


print '\n'.join('              {0}'.format(line) for line in [
                '---------------------------------------------------------------',
                'Value of a is'] + textwrap.fill(My_string, 20).split('\n') +
                ['---------------------------------------------------------------'])
```

prints

```
              ---------------------------------------------------------------
              Value of a is
              aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
              bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc
              cccccccccccccccccccd
              ddddddddddddddddddde
              eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef
              fffffffffffffffffff
              ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is there any solution, so we can do it with regular expressions...or some editing in my tried code

Comment: @SuryaGupta - you can replace the `textwrap.fill` code with your `re.findall` in order to get a list of wrapped lines.

Comment: +1, I've never even seen this module, and it looks spectacular

Comment: for me its showing error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/output.py", line 18, in <module>
    ['---------------------------------------------------------------'])
  File "/output.py", line 15, in <genexpr>
    print '\n'.join('              {}'.format(line) for line in [
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: I tried with re.findall, throwing error :   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/output.py", line 17, in <module>
    'Value of a is'] + re.findall(My_string, 20).split('\n') +
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 177, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @SuryaGupta - You are using Python 2.6, so please add a zero into the `format` definition. I added it for you in my answer.

Comment: @SuryaGupta - Change `re.findall(My_string, 20).split('\n')` to `re.findall("(?s).{,20}", My_string)`, because `findall` returns a list already. Anyway, that regexp is so ugly, that you should really have a look at `textwrap`, which does the job perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import re

My_string = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccddddddddddddddddddddeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffffffffffff"
split="\n     "
a = split.join(re.findall("(?s).{,20}", My_string))[0:-1]



print '''     ---------------------------------------------------------------
     Value of a is 
     %s ---------------------------------------------------------------''' % a
```

it looks like can meet your requirements